# mobile applications using richfaces

Tags: jsf, mobile, richfaces

is it possible to use mobile applications using Rich-faces 3.3? i know both ice-faces and prime-faces(it has a components called touch-faces) support mobile developments. if yes is there examples or information available on internet?

Thanks 
Soma

Answer (score 2):

You could but IMO it would be too heavy for a mobile environment - ie. the page sizes would be too large and the components aren't applicable for a mobile.

Go for something like [jqTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/) instead.

This [O'Reilly article on iPhone web development](http://building-iphone-apps.labs.oreilly.com/) is definitely worth a read too.